# Laravel route with multiple names

Tags: laravel, routes

Cant i have two names with one route?
Something like below:

```
Route::get('/', 'Admin\HomeController@index')->name(['admin.home', 'planner.home.index']);
```

Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to have 2 of the same route, differentiate by name

Comment: you mean this: Route::get('xxx')->name('admin.home');  Route::get('xxx')->name( 'planner.home.index');

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: i tried but it shown admin.home route not found. Maybe it was overwritten.

Comment: Try run ```php artisan route:list``` and make sure all the routes you want are listed

Answer (score 2):

This works only if you need the name, not the URL, although it's tricky and sloppy.

```
Route::get('/', 'Admin\HomeController@index')->name('admin.home');
Route::get('/2', function() {
    return redirect()->route('admin.home')
})->name('planner.home.index');
```

So if you use `route('admin.home')` or `route('planner.home.index')` it will redirects you to the method `index` in your `HomeController`.

Comment: With this answer you will have two _different_ routes, `/` and `/2`. The question asked is how to have the same route with two names.

Comment: As I said it is tricky and sloppy a bit. But the result is, when you want to use the route name in your blade, each one you use, it will return ONE same result.

Comment: Even though you end up at the same _location_, the result is definitely not the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this, if you seek to have 2 version(route name) in the same app.

```
    <?php

    $routes = ['v1' => 'app.name1.', 'v2' => 'app.name2.'];
    foreach ($routes as $routeVersion => $routeName) {

        // Yours router app (i.e app/v1/pages or app/v2/pages)
        // Your router name (i.e app.name1 or app.name2)
        Route::prefix('app' . $routeVersion)
            ->middleware('auth')
            ->name($routeName)
            ->group(function(){

               # Your custom routes
               ... 

            }
        }
    }

    ?>
```

This is an example of the response in the route list

[image: Result]]

I hope it serves you!

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach($pages as  $key => $page){
    Route::any("/".$page, "Controller@index")->name($page);
}
```